# linq query and select statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following linq

```
 var data = repository.FindAll().Where(x => x.Country.ID == ID).ToList();
 var serializedData = (from c in data select new { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name });
```

how can I this serializedData query simplify (combine) with first query?

Comment: I think you forgot a word in your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you should almost certainly get rid of the `ToList()` call, to start with - that way the selection part will be turned into SQL and avoid pulling down unnecessary data. You can do the whole thing in a query expression:

```
var serializedData = from x in repository.FindAll()
                     where x.Country.ID == ID
                     select new { x.ID, x.Name };
```

Note that if `FindAll()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IQueryable<T>`, you should see if there's another method which *does* return an appropriate `IQueryable<T>` - otherwise you're fetching the whole table from the database. (At least, I assume there's a database involved... you haven't given us much context.)

Comment: I have a feeling `FindAll` returns an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IQueryable`

Answer (score 1):

That should do it!

```
 var serializedData = repository.FindAll().Where(x => x.Country.ID == ID).Select( c => new { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
var serializedData = repository.FindAll().where(x=>x.CountryID == ID)
                               .Select(c=>new { c.ID ,c.Name }).ToList();
```